# Error: expected type-specifier before

Tags: c++, c++11, c++builder

The following block of code generated the errors

```
rating* TrustManager::initNewRating(double alpha, double beta, double fading)
{
   rating* rating = new rating(1.0, 1.0);
   rating->updateRating(alpha, beta, fading, 1);
   return rating;
}
```

the errors are

```
error: expected type-specifier before ‘rating’
error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘rating*’ in initialization
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘rating’
```

Comment: Go ahead and debug your problem.

Comment: Not sure if this solves your problem, but you shouldn't be calling classes and variables the same way (`rating* rating`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler does not know `rating`. #include it...